# how we get sum(column 1)-sum(column 2) using linq on datatable in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datatable, ado.net

There is two column in Dattemp table Dr and Cr. I need result sum(dr)-sum(cr) with where clause on dattemp in  opening balance column of datdetail table

```
       for (int i = 0; i < datDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            datDetail.Rows[i]["Opening Balance"] = Convert.ToDouble(DatTemp.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Identity ID") == Convert.ToInt32(datDetail.Rows[i]["Identity ID"]) && (r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= Convert.ToDateTime(TxtFromDate.Text.Trim()))).Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CR")) - DatTemp.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("DR"))).ToString("00.00");
            datDetail.Rows[i]["Clossing Balance"] = Convert.ToDouble(DatTemp.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Identity ID") == Convert.ToInt32(datDetail.Rows[i]["Identity ID"]) && (r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= Convert.ToDateTime(TxtToDate.Text.Trim()))).Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CR")) - DatTemp.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("DR"))).ToString("00.00");
        }

        GridDetails.DataSource = datDetail;
        GridDetails.DataBind();
```

Comment: What issue you had?

Comment: if you have already done the SUMs what is stopping you from doing the subtraction?

Comment: These "one-liners" are probably the most unreadable LINQ queries that i've seen so far. Use variables and use column names instead of indexes. No one will understand this including yourself

Comment: calculation not come proper

Comment: @gurmeetsingh: You should show samples, the current result and your desired result. What means "not proper"?

Comment: Opening Balance =sum(CR)-sum(DR) with where clause not correct or, Clossing Balance =sum(CR)-sm(DR) with where clause  not correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var openBal = DatTemp.Compute("Sum(OpeningBalance)", "");
var closeBal = DatTemp.Compute("Sum(ClosingBalance)", "");
var difference = Math.Abs(openBal - closeBal);//you may need to cast here
```

Comment: I do this but i need single statement for opening balance=sum(CR)-sum(DR) using linq on datatable

Comment: You can try like

var sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));

Comment: yes sir but i have now 10000 of rows and i know it increase that's why i need single statement. In for Loop it take time